# Cakephp 3.x migration: define foreign key dependencies / execution order

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, database-migration

#### System

- CakePHP Version: 3.4.6
- Platform and Target: MySQL 5.7, Windows 10

#### Problem

I'm defining a column as a foreign key within a **migration B** which needs a prior **table A** to exist / migration executed.

#### What happens

Of course the error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key` pops up because the migration of **table A** must be executed first so that B can define it's foreign key.

#### Question

Can I define the execution order / dependencies within the migrations or do I have to execute the migrations one by one by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is determined by the version (datetime) prefix of the migration filenames, they are being executed in ascending order, ie from the earliest to the latest version. Rollbacks are executed in descending order, ie from the latest to the earliest (as of Phinx 0.8, the rollback order can be defined via [**the `version_order` option**](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/configuration.html#version-order)).

So if you need your migrations to be applied in a specific order, set the versions of the filenames accordingly. Alternatively apply the changes in a single migration file.

Comment: In my opinion they didn't appropriately handle this important issue. What I did now was to disable the foreign key checks via SQL before the migration execution and enabled it afterwards again:  
```$this->execute('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');```